Sonar-Job in gitlab pipeline randomly crashes with java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

SonarQube: 10.5.1,
Scanner: 11.0
Plugin: sonar branch plugin
SonarQube deployed: Helm

Similar to this issue description, my pipeline randomly crashes on
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/platform/.git/.probe-f6b29551-6f66-4234-ad27-a007a01883b1
I have tried adding .git folder to sonar.exclusions using wild card patterns such as .git/**, **/.git/** but these issues keep on occurring randomly.
I have also tried to give concrete paths instead of sonar.source=. but the issue still remains
Any suggestions are highly appreciated
